# Rails: Unexpected tSTRING_BEG in rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I am trying to create a helper function to be used in my view for my **Rails** application.

I am using the `number_to_human` ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper method for formatting the values.

This is my implementation of the function:

```
def money(value, currency)
  return "N/A" unless value
  number_to_human(value, units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M' }) "#{currency}"
end
```

What I want to achieve is to parse the value of `currency`, which can be `$` OR any other currency depending on what I want.

However, I get the error below when I try testing:

> app/helpers/formatting_helpers.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end ...housand: 'K', million: 'M' }) "#{currency}" ... ^

If I remove the `"#{currency}"`, it works fine. But I need a way to pass the value of `currency` into the function.

How do I go about fixing this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the return value correctly, e.g.:

```rb
def money(value, currency)
  return "N/A" unless value
  number = number_to_human(value, units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M' }) 

  "#{number} #{currency}"
end
```